# Scheduled Sql Server Policy against Central Management Server group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know of a way to run a policy against a Central Management Server group?  In other words, run one policy off the Central Management Server that evaluates against x number of servers.  I want to run this on a scheduled basis.  It seems like a fairly common scenario to me, yet I can't seem to get it figured.

Apologies if this has been asked before, my stack-fu and google-fu seem to be missing the mark tonight.

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Enterprise Policy Management Framework on codeplex http://epmframework.codeplex.com/. There's a bunch of reports which go with it as well.

Comment: Great link, thanks for the suggestion.  This looks to accomplish what I am looking for.  I haven't had a chance to test it yet, I've being mercilessly beaten by the developers today, but after I get a chance to try it and see if it fulfills my needs I'll come back and mark it answered.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this out.  Great tool, exactly what we needed.  Much thanks!